# C# Set Variable in Thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, network-programming, threadpool

I'm trying to work with Threads for a private Project and I have a question which is, as I think very easy to answer.

Is it possible to set a variable in another thread?

Here a little Code example to show you what I'm trying to do:

```
public class PartyClass
{
     public boolean partytime = true;

     public void MakeParty()
     {
          while(partytime)
               Console.WriteLine("I'm making a party here");

          Console.WriteLine("The party ended. Please leave now");
     }

     public void StopParty()
     {
          partytime = false;
     }
}

public class MainThread
{
     public static int Main(String[] args)
     {
          PartyClass party = new PartyClass();
          Thread partyThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(party.MakeParty()));
          partyThread.Start();
          while (!partyThread.IsAlive) ;

          System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

          // Now I want to somehow call the StopParty() Method
     }
}
```

I don't know if it's really stupid what I'm trying to do but I think its a nice way to stop the "Partythread" in a clean way.

Is this possible or is there a better solution for this?
Thanks for your Ideas.

(I didn't test the Code - just wrote it out of my head)

Comment: Your main thread is waiting for the second thread to stop, and the second thread won't stop until the main thread tells it to.  It'll just go on forever at that rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the stop method just the way you called the start method:

```
party.StopParty();
```

In order to ensure that the changes made in another thread aren't just cached, the `partytime` field should be marked as `volatile` as well.

Comment: Like this?
'volatile bool partytime = true;'

Didn't know that I can call methods in other threads o.O :D

Comment: @greece57 Threads don't own methods, or objects, or memory (well, technically there is thread specific memory, but you need to go out of your way to create it).  The method doesn't belong to any one thread, different threads are simply accessing the methods, or memory, that are all globally accessible.

Answer (score 1):

You should use synchronization facilities, such as [CancellationToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Your code will look like:

```
public class PartyClass
{
    private readonly CancellationToken _cancellationToken;

    public PartyClass(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _cancellationToken = cancellationToken;
    }

    public void MakeParty()
    {
        while (!_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            Console.WriteLine("I'm making a party here");

        Console.WriteLine("The party ended. Please leave now");
    }
}

public class MainThread
{
    public static int Main(String[] args)
    {
        var cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        PartyClass party = new PartyClass(cancellationSource.Token);
        Thread partyThread = new Thread(party.MakeParty);
        partyThread.Start();

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

        cancellationSource.Cancel();

        partyThread.Join();
    }
}
```

It is thread-safe and suitable not only for this, but also for more advanced scenarios, as well as for working with tasks.

Comment: Can I use this Token also for multiple Threads and cancel them all with setting the one token?
Thanks for the response!

Comment: Yes, just path the same token (actually, copies of, because it's struct) to every thread you wish to cancel. More [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If want more threads to ask for the same variable, take care about thread syncrhonization issues (when two threads try to access the same variable).

Im going to show the safest way (might be more than what you need). The best to way to do it is declaring an static object to set a `lock` in order to make sure you have one thread changing the party flag at once.

```
public class PartyClass
{

    private object _partyTimeLock = new Object();  // executed at class init
    private boolean partyTime= true;

    public bool IsPartyGoingOn()
    {
       bool itIsGoingOn = false;
       lock(_partyTimeLock) {
          itIsGoingOn = partyTime;
       }
       return itIsGoingOn;
    }

    public void StopParty()
    {
        lock(_partyTimeLock) {
           partyTime = false;
        }
    }

    public void MakeParty()
    {
         while(IsPartyGoingOn()) {
              Console.WriteLine("I'm making a party here");
         }

         Console.WriteLine("The party ended. Please leave now");
    }
}
```

In this example here, no matter who try to call the IsPartyGoingOn(), you will never have an issue (no matter if it the class own thread or another one). The `lock` keyword will guarantee you are doing the right way.

Comment: Lock is for synchronization of access to common **resources**,  not for inter-thread signals. If you want to use the "conservative" API, use ManualResetEvent or its *Slim version.